# точка в центре карты

Tags: java, android

Как сделать чтоб маркер всегда был в центре камеры  на карте ?как в программах такси .Я сделал  так, создал маркер его местоположение добавил текущий центр камеры .Изменяю положения маркера меттодом setPosition маркер обновет св местоположение на новый центр при каждом движении камеры.Но мне надо чтоб он всегда находился в центре .Как такое сделать ???

Comment: Думаю, вам тут вообще маркер не нужен. Наверняка можно просто `ImageView` поверх карты по центру экрана расположить и всё

Comment: @ЮрийСПб   ахахахаха Юрий вы правы так и сделал :)))))Юрий и ещё кое что как сделать чтоб на кнопке знак стрелки анимировслева направо ???)

Comment: Не очень ясно какая вам анимация нужна, но можно как-то так попробовать: `imageView.animate().rotateBy(90).setDuration(1000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае самый простой способ - просто `ImageView` поверх карты по центру экрана расположить и всё.